# Dead Sea historical measurements 1930s to 1970s

Tags: data-request, historical

I'm looking for historical Dead Sea water levels data. There's a good sequence from 1976 until today on a monthly basis, but there are some graphs that show measurement data from the 1930s.

I'm looking for that data in spreadsheet/table form.

[image]

Comment: What is the source of the graph that is posted?

Answer (score 2):

Some reverse image searching gives this [Wikipedia citation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Sea#cite_note-55), which then gives this [website](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Peace/water2.html), which cites this dead website ([wayback machine archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20111003042037/http://www.exact-me.org/overview/index.htm)), which hosted a [report](http://web.archive.org/web/20120619051148/http://exact-me.org/overview/index_pdf.htm) which contains this [PDF page 43](http://web.archive.org/web/20120524171245/http://exact-me.org/overview/p43.pdf)

[image]

> Historical water-level records of the Dead Sea have been reconstructed for a period of over 1,000 years, including the very large rise and fall in water level around the first century B.C. (**modified from C. Klein, 1985**).

and this [PDF page 44](http://web.archive.org/web/20120524171318/http://exact-me.org/overview/p44.pdf)

[image]

> Water-level trends of the Dead Sea respond to measured rainfall trends in the watershed, except for the last three decades, when the effects of water use dominate the water-level trend.

which seems to cite this paper from C. Klein in 1985

> Klein, C., 1985, Fluctuations of the level of the Dead Sea and climatic fluctuations in the country during historical times: International Asso-ciation of Hydrological Sciences, Symposium, Scientific basis for water resources management, September, 1985, Jerusalem, Israel, p. 197-224.

which is oft cited but appears not to be [online](https://scholar.google.ch/scholar?hl=en&q=%22Fluctuations%20of%20the%20level%20of%20the%20Dead%20Sea%20and%20climatic%20fluctuations%20in%20the%20country%20during%20historical%20times%22&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=). You may need a university affiliation or some sort of interlibrary loan.

[image]

(Here's a related paper [PDF](https://www2.meteo.uni-bonn.de/bibliothek/Flohn_Publikationen/K321-K349_1985-1990/K333.pdf))

---

You'll also notice in the [report](http://web.macam.ac.il/~arnon/Int-ME/water/Jordan%20River/Overview%20of%20Middle%20East%20Water%20Resources.htm) that they list their sources:

- Jordanian Ministry of Water and Irrigation
- Palestinian Water Authority
- [**Israeli Hydrological Service**](http://www.water.gov.il/Pages/default.aspx)
- Israeli Meteorological Service

So you may have to start looking around and asking there.

Here's a link to [translated hydrological data](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.water.gov.il%2Fhebrew%2FPages%2Fhome.aspx&edit-text=). I'd contact that org directly, unless you can read Hebrew. If you get the data in PDFs and put it into a machine readable format, I'm sure the rest of us would appreciate sharing it!